# How can you duplicate weapons in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to get 2 identical *Unkempt Harolds* for my Gunzerker, and I do not want to Tourge token grind. I have one already, but I want to get another. How would I duplicate with the newest version of PC BL2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duping works just like it did on Borderlands 1, you simply have a friend make a multiplayer game, join as a guest, drop the item(s) you want, then force quit the game (alt F4, don't use the menu). If all works as planned, the host will still have those items, and since your game didn't save the state of you not having the item, your character has it too.

The character duping weapons should join as a guest so this goes smoothly. I'm not aware of any way to do this single player on PC or console (though single players on PC can simply use the [Gibbed Save editor](http://blog.gib.me/category/games/borderlands-2/) to do basically the same thing). Do NOT do this with random matchmaking players, do it with friends for obvious reliability reasons.

Since there's no particularly simple way to prevent this, duping has never been (effectively) patched out of the game.

Note if you do this, Steam may complain about cloud saves not matching local saves. Always continue on local saves when doing this, as your cloud save is probably out of date due to the force quit.

Comment: Personally I reckon they should do the local saves like FTL - remove the save from disk on load, so if you quit out prematurely that save is lost. if there is no local save (i.e. someone tried this), reload save from cloud. Periodically re-save to the cloud, and on a successful exit, save a local copy (for offline/no network play)

Comment: Gibbed Borderlands 2 save editor works too

Comment: [Link](http://blog.gib.me/category/games/borderlands-2/) to the save editor, FYI

Comment: @spyder oh good point, added info about that. That's a good option for people who only play single player

Comment: You can do it in single player on PC by simply duplicating your save file (so you have twice the same character) and putting the gear you want to have twice from the duped char in your shared stash (near clap trap in sanctuary) so your main character can get it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a trade with a **friend** put the weapon in there duel them and then drop the weapon and let them kill you they get a copy you pick your gun back up and they all lived happily ever after

Answer (score 1):

Go online and go into trade. Instead duel, then once you have started fighting, drop the weapon you want to duplicate and simply lose. The other player should of had gotten it and the item will still be on the floor